# An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request while connecting to SQL Server in docker

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core

I have docker compose file as:

```
     version: "3.8"
      services:
    web:
     build: .
    ports:
        - "8019:80"
    depends_on:
        - db
db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
    environment:
        SA_PASSWORD: "Mypassword123!"
        ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

And Db connection string as:

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=db;Database=Client;User=SA;Password=Mypassword123!;"
```

But it throws an error:

> ExtendedSocketException: Name or service not known

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGBcN.png

Comment: **Word of caution**: I would recommend to **NEVER** use your `sa` user in any connection string! Create an application specific login/user and provide that in the connection string....

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a firewall issue. Is your database in Azure? if so go to firewall page and add IP address of the system you are trying to connect from.